# How to turn a "paragraph" into a list

Tags: python, list, paragraph

I apologize in advance as I do not know how to properly ask this question. Every week, I get earnings reports on stock updates. And they come looking like this

```
Alexandria Real Estate Equities, Inc. (ARE), Beyond Meat, Inc. (BYND), Brown & Brown, Inc. (BRO), Canon Inc. (CAJ), 
Chegg, Inc. (CHGG), Cincinnati Financial Co. (CINF), Ecopetrol SA (EC), Hasbro, Inc. (HAS), 
HCA Healthcare, Inc. (HCA), HSBC Holdings plc (HSBC), NXP Semiconductors (NXPI), Otis Worldwide (OTIS), 
Packaging Co. of America (PKG), Petróleo Brasileiro S.A. - Petrobras (PBR), Principal Financial Group Inc (PFG), 
Principal Financial Group, Inc. (PFG), SAP SE (SAP), Twilio Inc (TWLO)
```

And since this message comes via email, I want to find a way to store it in a `.txt` that looks visibly appealing. If possible, I would like to make it look like

```
[1] Alexandria real estate equities, inc. (ARE)
[2] Beyond meat, inc. (BYND)
[3] Brown & brown, inc. (BRO)
[4] Canon inc. (CAJ)
[5] Chegg, inc. (CHGG)
[6] Cincinnati financial co. (CINF)
[7] Ecopetrol sa  (EC)
[8] Hasbro, inc. (HAS)
```

And so on. Despite my constant thinking and laying out different options, I am still stuck and do not know how to approach this. ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would go like this..

```py
import re

stocks = re.split(r'(?<=\)),\s', stocks_string.replace('\n','')
for index, stock in enumerate(stocks):
    print(f'[{index+1}] {stock}'
```

I am using regex split to retain the the closing bracket at the end of the stock name. (?<=) is called "look behind" and overall regex will match the coma only if closing bracket precedes it.

Comment: I just tried this and it works well, but for 1,5,9,13,16, it prints it on the next line? What is happening there?

Comment: It is because the string you provided seem to have the line breaks in it. Then, we need to modify a regex a bit, to make it work. Let me edit it.

Comment: Or a better solution, just remove the line breaks. And also, with \s we can remove the whitespace that is standing before each element in a list.

Answer (score 2):

We can see that each of the stocks are separated by `,` . But since the same `,`  character is also used for ", Inc." , we'll need to separate the stock names by `),` .

Let's split the text using Python's inbuilt `split()` function. We get a list of strings from text. Like this:

```
text = "Alexandria Real Estate Equities, Inc. (ARE), Beyond Meat, Inc. (BYND), Brown & Brown, Inc. (BRO), Canon Inc. (CAJ), Chegg, Inc. (CHGG), Cincinnati Financial Co. (CINF), Ecopetrol SA (EC), Hasbro, Inc. (HAS), HCA Healthcare, Inc. (HCA), HSBC Holdings plc (HSBC), NXP Semiconductors (NXPI), Otis Worldwide (OTIS), Packaging Co. of America (PKG), Petróleo Brasileiro S.A. - Petrobras (PBR), Principal Financial Group Inc (PFG), Principal Financial Group, Inc. (PFG), SAP SE (SAP), Twilio Inc (TWLO)"

split_text = text.split("), ")
```

The output:

```
['Alexandria Real Estate Equities, Inc. (ARE', 'Beyond Meat, Inc. (BYND', 'Brown & Brown, Inc. (BRO', 'Canon Inc. (CAJ', 'Chegg, Inc. (CHGG', 'Cincinnati Financial Co. (CINF', 'Ecopetrol SA (EC', 'Hasbro, Inc. (HAS', 'HCA Healthcare, Inc. (HCA', 'HSBC Holdings plc (HSBC', 'NXP Semiconductors (NXPI', 'Otis Worldwide (OTIS', 'Packaging Co. of America (PKG', 'Petróleo Brasileiro S.A. - Petrobras (PBR', 'Principal Financial Group Inc (PFG', 'Principal Financial Group, Inc. (PFG', 'SAP SE (SAP', 'Twilio Inc (TWLO)']
```

Let's append the lost `)` character at the end.

To get the index of each stock, use the `enumerate()` function in a loop.

The final code:

```
split_text = text.split("), ")
for idx, stock_name in enumerate(split_text):
    print(f"[{idx+1}] {stock_name})")
```

Output:

```
[1] Alexandria Real Estate Equities, Inc. (ARE)
[2] Beyond Meat, Inc. (BYND)
[3] Brown & Brown, Inc. (BRO)
[4] Canon Inc. (CAJ)
[5] Chegg, Inc. (CHGG)
[6] Cincinnati Financial Co. (CINF)
[7] Ecopetrol SA (EC)
[8] Hasbro, Inc. (HAS)
[9] HCA Healthcare, Inc. (HCA)
[10] HSBC Holdings plc (HSBC)
[11] NXP Semiconductors (NXPI)
[12] Otis Worldwide (OTIS)
[13] Packaging Co. of America (PKG)
[14] Petróleo Brasileiro S.A. - Petrobras (PBR)
[15] Principal Financial Group Inc (PFG)
[16] Principal Financial Group, Inc. (PFG)
[17] SAP SE (SAP)
[18] Twilio Inc (TWLO)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text file is always in that format: "Full name here (SHORT)" Then we can use the simple python split as we know there will always be a "), " between each term. This split will return an array of all the values you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To give it the format you need, I'd do:

```
res = [f"[{index+1}] {i})".replace(", ","").replace("\n","") for index, i in enumerate(text.split(")"))]
res.pop()
output = "".join([f"{i}\n" for i in res])
print(output)
```

Prints out

```
[1] Alexandria Real Estate EquitiesInc. (ARE)
[2] Beyond MeatInc. (BYND)
[3] Brown & BrownInc. (BRO)
[4] Canon Inc. (CAJ)
[5] CheggInc. (CHGG)
[6] Cincinnati Financial Co. (CINF)
[7] Ecopetrol SA (EC)
[8] HasbroInc. (HAS)
[9] HCA HealthcareInc. (HCA)
[10] HSBC Holdings plc (HSBC)
[11] NXP Semiconductors (NXPI)
[12] Otis Worldwide (OTIS)
[13] Packaging Co. of America (PKG)
[14] Petróleo Brasileiro S.A. - Petrobras (PBR)
[15] Principal Financial Group Inc (PFG)
[16] Principal Financial GroupInc. (PFG)
[17] SAP SE (SAP)
[18] Twilio Inc (TWLO)
```